# knockout replace - native binding directive on the fly

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have a bit of a weird use case where i need to change the following prior to applying bindings.

```
<!-- ko foreach: model.dogs-->
html
<!-- /ko -->
```

to
    
    html

This is what I have so far but I'm not sure how to update the comment elements in the dom

```
var commented = $el.contents().filter(function(){
return this.nodeType == 8;
})
commented.each(function(i, item){
//replace text
//item.replace("dogs", "dogs2");
})
```

Any pointers much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get and set domelement nodes with nodeValue.

```
item.nodeValue = item.nodeValue.replace('dogs', 'dogs2');
```

Supported on all browsers: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html

Comment: If you're ever in Japan, a cold beer is waiting. you beauty!

Answer (score 0):

Don't mess with the DOM. Modifying the comment on the low-level DOM API won't magically update your high-level view. Just create a proper ViewModel that handles this kind of situation.

```
dogs1 = ko.observableArray([1,2,3]);
dogs2 = ko.observableArray([4,5,6]);

viewModel.dogGroup = ko.observable("dogs1");
viewModel.displayedDogs = ko.computed(function() {
    return (viewModel.tab() == "dogs1" ? dogs1() : dogs2());
  });
```

Comment: tricky, I'm stuck with html snippets coming in with the comments. I want to apply different models to these snippets. I've been successful with changing the data-bind parts but not the comments yet. thanks